# jQuery event on NiceForms drop down change

Tags: jquery, niceforms

Im using niceForms to make my drop downs and below is what I have in my html

```
<select style="width:1px;" class="NFhidden" size="1" id="aics_Enquiry" name="aics_Enquiry">
    <option value="0">General enquiry</option>
    <option value="1"> Request a statement</option>
    <option value="2"> Feedback</option>
    <option value="3"> Other</option>
</select>
```

But when I use firbug on my drop down item, it shows the following html too which I just cant see on my Source code if I view it on the browser.

```
 <dd style="width:" class="relative fl">
 <div class="NFSelect" style="width: 5px; left: 767px; top: 593px; z-index: 999;"><img src="/templates/liberty/images/0.png" class="NFSelectLeft">
 <div class="NFSelectRight">Feedback</div>
 <div class="NFSelectTarget" style="display: none;">
 <ul class="NFSelectOptions">
 <li><a href="javascript:;">General enquiry</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;">Request a statement</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="NFOptionActive">Feedback</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;">Other</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 <select style="width:1px;" class="NFhidden" size="1" id="aics_Enquiry" name="aics_Enquiry">
 <option value="0">General enquiry</option>
 <option value="1"> Request a statement</option>
 <option value="2"> Feedback</option>
 <option value="3"> Other</option>
 </select>
 </dd>
```

My question is, I want to trigger a jquery event when someone changes the menu to 'Feedback' drop down item. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/change/)`change()`

```
$("#aics_Enquiry").change( function(){
 if(this.value == 2){
  //TODO: implement solution
 }
});
```

Comment: @undefined - I usually default back to plain javascript for element access because it tends to be faster.

Comment: Yes, it's a good practice, currently you are making a jQuery object and then converting it to a DOM object, I meant why not coding `this.value` directly?

Comment: @undefined - Oh, that was a misunderstanding on my part. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks. But this didnt work. I used  $("body").html("test"); in if part, but nothing happened? Can you help? My concern is with NiceForm, it doesnt chagne the drop down select list.

Comment: @Uds You should first load the jQuery in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/43xwY/4/\

Comment: @undefined Thanks. it works fine in here, but it doesnt work with NiceForms because NiceForm hides the "select" drop down and displays some dives and ULs like I have on my question above. Please have a look at this working example : http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/niceforms.html